# Get a picture - Python-pptx

Tags: python, image, python-pptx

I am trying to read a .pptx file using `python-pptx`. I managed to get all the content except the image from the presentation. Below is the code i used to identify images other than textframes in the presentation. After identifying i am getting the `auto_shape_type` as `RECTANGLE (1)` but nothing about the image.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.shapes.picture import Picture

def read_ppt(file):
    prs = Presentation(file)
    for slide_no, slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if not shape.has_text_frame:
                print(shape.auto_shape_type)
```

Any help on understanding this problem appreciated. Alternative options are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try querying the `shape.shape_type`. by default, the [`auto_shape_type`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.picture.Picture.auto_shape_type) returns rectangle as you've observed, though pictures can be inserted into and masked by other shapes as well.

> Note the default value for a newly-inserted picture is **`MSO_AUTO_SHAPE_TYPE.RECTANGLE`**, which performs no cropping because the extents of the rectangle exactly correspond to the extents of the picture.

the [`shape_type`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.picture.Picture.shape_type) should return:

> Unique integer identifying the type of this shape, unconditionally **`MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.PICTURE`** in this case.

You can extract the image content to a file by using its `blob` property and writing out the binary:

```
from pptx import Presentation
pres = Presentation('ppt_image.pptx')
slide = pres.slides[0]
shape = slide.shapes[0]
image = shape.image
blob = image.blob
ext = image.ext
with open(f'image.{ext}', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(blob)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Do you mind helping me in extracting the image from ppt?

Comment: @SmashGuy does this solve the question? I'm not sure what you mean by "extracting the image"? You can refer to the [`image`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.picture.Picture.image) property which returns an [`Image`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/image.html#pptx.parts.image.Image) object.

Comment: Yes. You have understood the question in the correct way. And the code helped me to finish my task. Thanks a lot.